# Создать (распределить) данные в объекте (HTML парсер)

Tags: парсер, javascript

Ребят выручайте, сам что то додуматься не могу.

Есть страница с таким куском кода:

```
<div class="block">
    <ul>
        <li class="block-model">
            <a href="url" class="link-par">Model 1</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="block-model">
            <a href="url" class="link-par">Model 2</a>
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="list-links"><a href="url">116</a></li>
                <li class="list-links"><a href="url">200</a></li>
                <li class="list-links"><a href="url">301</a></li>
                <li class="list-links"><a href="url">306</a></li>
                <li class="list-links"><a href="url">708</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Нужно создать объект вида в котором будет основная группа с название "Модель 1, Модель 2 и т.д.", а так же к группе будет подключена ее подгруппа с ссылками из блока .list

```
{
models: [
    {
        group: {
            name: "Model 1",
            url: "Model 1"
        },
        subgroup: [] // тут ничего нет так как в первом блоке кроме Model 1 ничего нет
    },
    {
        group: {
            name: "Model 2",
            url: "Model 2"
        },
        subgroup: [
            {
                name: "116",
                url: "116"
            },
            {
                name: "200",
                url: "200"
            },
            {
                name: "301",
                url: "301"
            },
            {
                name: "306",
                url: "306"
            },
            {
                name: "708",
                url: "708"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

С группами проблем не возникло, а вот с субгруппами не могу разобраться, пишу так

```
var obj.group = new Array()
, obj.subgroup = new Array();

$(".link-par").each(function () {

    obj.group.push({
        "name": $(this).text().trim(),
        "url": $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase().replace(/^(\s+)$/, '-')
    });

});
console.log(obj);
```

В общем, нужно к group прицепить все ее subgroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так пониамю, что подгруппа должна быть вложена в основную группу? Если я правильно понял, то [смотрите такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/pbpaosx0/):

```
var group = $('.block > ul'),
    res = {};
res.models = [];

function getSub(s){
    var tmp = [];
    s.each(function(i, el){
        tmp.push({
            name: $('a', el).text(),
            url: $('a', el).attr('href')
        });
    });
    return tmp;
}
for(var i = 0; i < group.length; i++){
    var curGroup = $('.block-model',group.eq(i)),
        linkpar = $('.link-par', curGroup);
    res.models.push({
        name: linkpar.text(),
        url: linkpar.attr('href'),
        subgroup: getSub( linkpar.siblings('.list').find('.list-links') )
    });

}
console.log(res);
```

P.S. Хотя, если в вопросе вы показали такую структуру, которая должна быть, то тогда ближе к делу будет [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/pbpaosx0/1/).

Comment: Что то у меня не получается нифига, в HTML много лишнего.
Если сможете глянуть, будет супер, вот блок html:

     https://yadi.sk/d/3mH51t_zZMB89

Из него нужно получить такой объект

 {
  "models": [
   {
    "group": {
     "name": "02 (E10)",
     "ulr": "url",
     "subgroup": []
    }
   },
   {
    "group": {
     "name": "1er",
     "url": "url",
     "subgroup": [
      {
       "name": "116",
       "url": "url"     
      },
      {
       "name": "118",
       "url": "url"     
      },
      {
       "name": "120",
       "url": "url"     
      }
     ]
    }
   }
  ]
 }

Comment: @webphp, ну вы даёте... А главное, что искренне удивляетесь тому, что не работает ))) Сударь, какую структуру показали - на такую я и ориентировался. Теперь, чтобы не было разночтений, рассказывайте по классам и элементам: что откуда берем и как раскидываем в объекте.

----------

P.S. По ходу, я кажется сам разобрался. [Смотрите сюда][1]. Всё так?

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/pbpaosx0/2/

Comment: да да да, все так. Огромное спасибо =)

   > Сударь, какую структуру показали - на такую я и ориентировался.

Сори, я как последний нубас, раскрыл глаза и побег сюда чтобы помогли решить вчерашнюю задачку =) Извиняюсь, тупанул жестко!